# python script more than one function

Tags: python-3.4

If your python script contains two or more functionalities, how can you run the script continuously to allow the user to select any one of these functionalities without restarting your program in a new IDLE console?

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the user for input with the `input` prompt and decide what to do based on the input like this:

```
response = input("Please enter your name: ")

if (response == "John"):
    fun_1(something)
else:
    fun_2(something_else)
```

The input prompt will wait for user input and record every input up to a carriage return (ENTER).